# CSS elements stay inline unintentionally

Tags: html, css, navbar, inline

I have made a navigatation bar for one of my website projects and all the HTML elements that I am trying to add after are staying in line with the navbar. I have checked for any open HTML tags or any syntax error or overlapping CSS styles but didn't solve the problem the only way I can get the elements in proper position is using absolute positioning, but I do not want to use that as I want my site to be flexible.

```css
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
}

nav a:link,
nav a:visited {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url("http://localhost/prosoft_noi_orizonturi/images/header-cover.jpg");
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

header h1 {
  color: rgba(256, 256, 256, .8);
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1>Bun venit,
      <?php echo $_SESSION['user']?>!</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.php">Acas&#259;</a></li>
      <li><a href="search.php">C&#259;utare</a></li>
      <li><a href="w8form.php">Formular W-8</a></li>
      <li><a href="notification.php">Notific&#259;ri</a></li>
      <li><a href="message.php">Mesaje</a></li>
      <li><a href="cont.php">Cont</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

An overview of the problem in browser

[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What happens if you remove the `float: left` rule?

Comment: It breaks the nav bar, but the position  of the rest of the content doesn't change.

Comment: This really rather shouldn't be done using inline and/or float any more these days (flexbox and grid exist), but if you want to keep using it like this, then you need to _clear the float_, so that following elements do not float next to this any more.

Comment: Have you tried to inspect `header` using debug tools? Is it `float` or anything? What size does it have?

Comment: It's not clear what you want as a result - you should describe it better

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
}

nav a:link,
nav a:visited {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url("http://localhost/prosoft_noi_orizonturi/images/header-cover.jpg");
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

header h1 {
  color: rgba(256, 256, 256, .8);
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1>Bun venit,
      <?php echo $_SESSION['user']?>!</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.php">Acas&#259;</a></li>
      <li><a href="search.php">C&#259;utare</a></li>
      <li><a href="w8form.php">Formular W-8</a></li>
      <li><a href="notification.php">Notific&#259;ri</a></li>
      <li><a href="message.php">Mesaje</a></li>
      <li><a href="cont.php">Cont</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: I am sorry it did not solved the problem. I think I will try a grid or flexbox approach. Thank you for your time.

Comment: The navbar code was not the problem. I have set display: flex; on the body and this threw things off.

Comment: Please add the code for body as well. It will be more clear and easier to debug with the full page's code.

Comment: the code for body after fixing: body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: black;
    color: red;
    font-family: "Major Mono Display", monospace;
}

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is remove `float: left;` from `nav ul` and it's now not-inlined.

```css
nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  /* float: left; */
}

nav a:link,
nav a:visited {
  background-color: brown;
  color: white;
  display: block;
  width: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0;
}

nav a:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-image: url("http://localhost/prosoft_noi_orizonturi/images/header-cover.jpg");
  margin-bottom: 70px;
}

header h1 {
  color: rgba(256, 256, 256, .8);
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <h1>Bun venit,
      <?php echo $_SESSION['user']?>!</h1>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="home.php">Acas&#259;</a></li>
      <li><a href="search.php">C&#259;utare</a></li>
      <li><a href="w8form.php">Formular W-8</a></li>
      <li><a href="notification.php">Notific&#259;ri</a></li>
      <li><a href="message.php">Mesaje</a></li>
      <li><a href="cont.php">Cont</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```